# Crystal Reports 2016 Sum field on two groups

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I have a report that sums data and I am trying to modify it.  I am trying to break out the totals by week by machine instead of one grand total by machine.  Example of the calculations look like the following:

```
numberVar x := Sum ({WorkCntrSummary.Downtime_DurationInMinutes_Category0}, {WorkCntrSummary.Criteria_MachineID});
numberVar xh := Truncate(Round(x)/60);
numberVar xm := Round(x) mod 60;

if xh >= 1 then
  ToText (xh, 0) + "h " + ToText (xm, 0) + "m"
else
  ToText (xm, 0) + "m"
```

I am trying to change the 1st line where it is summing the field by MachineID.  I want to sum it on the MachineID and also on a different group I added to the report which is a date field grouped by week.  I am at a loss as to how to change that sum to add the date field by week to it.  I tried changing it to the following, which doesn't do anything with grouping by week.

```
numberVar x := Sum ({WorkCntrSummary.Downtime_DurationInMinutes_Category0}, {WorkCntrSummary.Criteria_MachineID},{WorkCntrSummary.Criteria_StartDateTime});
numberVar xh := Truncate(Round(x)/60);
numberVar xm := Round(x) mod 60;

if xh >= 1 then
  ToText (xh, 0) + "h " + ToText (xm, 0) + "m"
else
  ToText (xm, 0) + "m"
```

But I get an error group condition must be a string.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Sum ({WorkCntrSummary.Downtime_DurationInMinutes_Category0}, {WorkCntrSummary.Criteria_MachineID},{WorkCntrSummary.Criteria_StartDateTime})
```

to

```
Sum ({WorkCntrSummary.Downtime_DurationInMinutes_Category0}, {WorkCntrSummary.Criteria_StartDateTime})
```

In Crystal, the 2nd argument is what you group on. No need to chain all the grouping elements.

Comment: When I change the formula to use the StartDateTime field it says "There must be a group that matches this field."  I do have a group on that field set to be printed for each week so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Change to 
Sum ({WorkCntrSummary.Downtime_DurationInMinutes_Category0}, {WorkCntrSummary.Criteria_StartDateTime}, "weekly")

Comment: It would make your life much easier if you first create the sum by selecting what you want to sum in the detail section and using the sigma button to create subtotals for all group levels. Once a subtotal field is created, you can paste the expression for it in the formula editor by looking for Report Fields with a sigma icon and the proper level of grouping. A double-click on such a sigma report field choice then pastes the whole expression for you, so you don't have to guess at the syntax.
Here's an image clarifying the text above: https://www.screencast.com/t/B0WEntBaAAn

Comment: Thank you so much MilletSoftware it worked perfectly once I had the parameters correct.  Appreciate your help!